# Interfacing an existing API with new classes

Tags: c#, opentk

Consider the OpenTK library which wraps opengl for c#. It comes with built in matrix classes that the API expects you to use. For example, the overloads in this method.

```
    public static void UniformMatrix4(int location, bool transpose, ref Matrix4 matrix);
    public static void UniformMatrix4(int location, bool transpose, ref Matrix4d matrix);
    public static void UniformMatrix4(int location, int count, bool transpose, double* value);
    public static void UniformMatrix4(int location, int count, bool transpose, double[] value);
    public static void UniformMatrix4(int location, int count, bool transpose, float* value);
    public static void UniformMatrix4(int location, int count, bool transpose, float[] value);
    public static void UniformMatrix4(int location, int count, bool transpose, ref double value);
    public static void UniformMatrix4(int location, int count, bool transpose, ref float value);
```

All of the API follows the same form. As an alternative to using the built in matrix class, I can use use a float pointer or float array, etc.

Now, I don't want to use OpenTK's matrix class or any other of their math structs, but I do want to use their API. What options do I have with interfacing my own Matrix class to the api, that is both clean and efficient.

The internal storage of my matrix class does not use a float[] but rather float fields. I don't think there is a way to extract a float array for passing to the API without inefficiently copying the fields into a new array.

Comment: The usual way to pass pointers to low level api's, is to declare struct with layouting attributes or to use arrays. If your show your class, It could be more clear what's possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unsafe possibility to use an low-level pointer's operations in C# (see [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx)), so you can get the address of the first float element, and you can pass it to OpenTK's functions.

I think, you could use "fixed arrays" (see same link), if you can re-implement your own Matrix class.